# IBM RAD 8 Unable to deploy second ear file ONLY from within RAD

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere, java-ee-6, jndi

Actions below are from **within the RAD**

I have two ear projects, with **myEar**.ear and **myXEar**.ear

myEar.ear **depends** on an ejb client module, that is part of myXEar.ear

First I start the **server**, and then add myXEar.ear to the server and that **works fine**.

**Second,** I add myEar.ear but it **breaks** when it hits trying binding the ejbs with **message**:

```
[10/15/12 10:46:33:915 CEST] 0000008f EJBContainerI E   WSVR0039E: Unable to start EJB jar, ManageInfoHeaderFacadeBean: The com.volvo.myEarx.facade.b.ManageInfoHeaderFacade interface of the ManageInfoHeaderFacadeBean bean in the myEarXFacadeEJB-5.2.27_M2ECLIPSE_UPGRADE-SNAPSHOT-client.jar module of the myEarEar application cannot be bound to the ejb/ManageInfoHeaderFacade name location. The com.volvo.myEarx.facade.b.ManageInfoHeaderFacade interface of the ManageInfoHeaderFacadeBean bean in the myEarXFacadeEJB-5.2.27_M2ECLIPSE_UPGRADE-SNAPSHOT.jar module of the myEarXEar application has already been bound to the ejb/ManageInfoHeaderFacade name location.
```

The EJBs have already been registered during the startup of myEarX.ear ... so now we are running into the issue when **this second ear** file which references the same ejb module tries to **"start it"**.

> Why is it not working from within the RAD? 
>   Everything works **fine** from the **webconsole**, but I need to make
>   this work from **within the RAD.**

I have looked at org.eclipse.wst.common.**component** files and what not.. but could not figure it out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have two EAR projects, and both of them include the same EJB module. The EJB module has a bean, which is bound into `ejb/ManageInfoHeaderFacade`. Deploying the two EAR modules on the server will result in an error, because of a JNDI naming conflict.

I severely doubt that it works flawlessly through the web admin console. I suspect that, when you're deploying through the web admin console, you make it work by either manually assigning JNDI names to beans, *or* selecting a prefix to the JNDI names of the beans. That way, each bean has its own distinct JNDI name.

In RAD, there is no way of doing so (at least not in RAD 8.0).

Comment: Hi Isaac. Your interpretation is correct, but actually I missed out that, the shared EJB module, also has thinner xxxejb-client.jar defined in its pom file which is the one actually referenced by the second project. Not sure if that is relevant. This has been working for a long time, and workes well, with no manual steps in the admin console. The definition of the beans are in the modules ejb bindings. Note that this has been working in Rad 7.5 as well.

Comment: Well, this is relevant. I think it's best if you describe what both applications do with the EJB. I get the sense that one application is actually "hosting" the EJB, and the other application (which refers to the EJB client JAR) is only invoking remote methods on that EJB. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes it appears so. myXEar.ear contains the facade.jar and then the other one refers to facade-client.jar which is a thin package with just class names, but is actually built in the facades own pom.. but referenced from the modules in myEar and in .eclipse...component file .. 

      `<dependency>
      <groupId>com.volvo.myApp</groupId>
      <artifactId>MyAppFacadeEJB</artifactId>
      <version>${myApp.version}</version>
      <type>ejb-client</type>`

Comment: can't think of something? I think it has to do with the files under .settings in various modules...

Comment: What I understand from your explanation is that `myXEar.ear` is the application actually containing the EJB, and `myEar.ear` contains some JavaEE modules that would like to access the EJB, but not to actually 'host' it. In that case, `myEar.ear` should **not** include `facade.jar`, but only include `facade-client.jar`. `myEar.ear` doesn't want to deploy an EJB, but instead it wants to use an existing one (from `myXEar.ear`) remotely. Therefore, ensure that the EJB module (`facade.jar`) is not referenced by `myEar.ear`, redeploy and test.